# As a library, should I move my extends to AppCompatTextView/ImageView instead Normal TextView/ImageView

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat

I'm making library that extends from `TextView` and `ImageView`. Someone requested me to extend from [`AppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html) and [`AppCompatImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) instead so that it would be backward compatible (to I don't know what version... can't find the info).

My library already being used by others. If I change my library to extends from [`AppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html) and [`AppCompatImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) instead of from `TextView` and `ImageView`, will there be impact to my existing user in term or usage (e.g. they have to modify their code, xml attribute)... or performance (e.g. slower, memory)? Or it is pure gain, i.e. AppCompat version is the superset of the normal version, and AppCompat is more backward compatible?

Comment: Make AppCompat variant.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you, @EugenPerchanec. You mean AppCompat is better than the normal one, and has no side effect?

Comment: AppCompat widgets are a must for people who use AppCompat. Not all people use AppCompat. Make an AppCompat variant of your library in addition to what you have and distribute it as a separate artifact dependent on appcompat-v7 and your original library.